# Whats the difference between Backbone.Model.extend() vs class X extends Backbone.Model?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

In JavaScript, I will have to use

```
Backbone.Model.extend()
```

To create a "Class" for my model. But in CoffeeScript I can use

```
class X extends Backbone.Model
```

Whats the difference between the 2. Is there any reason why I should use one over the other?

A simple test to see whats the diff http://jsfiddle.net/jiewmeng/t6ZPd/

```
Test = Backbone.Model.extend()
class Test2 extends Backbone.Model

console.log Test
/*
function (){return i.apply(this,arguments)} 
*/

console.log Test2
/*
function Test2() {
    _ref = Test2.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
    return _ref;
  } 
*/
```

I believe its not showing all the code ... but the `extends()` seems slightly simpler. JUst curious is there any other differences?

Comment: Just compare the code in Model.extend() to what the CoffeeScript compiles to...

Comment: One is Backbone's way of extending Backbone classes, the other is the general way of extending a class provided by coffeescript, which will do exactly the same (as it'll call `Backbone.Model`'s constructor, which is the line you can see with your first log). However they may be different if you happen to override the constructor when extending with Backbone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

coffeescript creates the extends method at the top of the closure:

```
__extends = function(child, parent) { for (var key in parent) { if (__hasProp.call(parent, key)) child[key] = parent[key]; } function ctor() { this.constructor = child; } ctor.prototype = parent.prototype; child.prototype = new ctor(); child.__super__ = parent.prototype; return child; };
```

underscore defines it as such: http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-76

The implementation is slightly different but the effect is the same.

If you are using Backbone or more specifically Underscore, you can choose to do either method, but `extends` in coffeescript allows you to extend any class without the need of a dependency like Underscore or Backbone.

An example of what you can do with the method while using backbone might be overriding the constructor to provide optional items to the class that backbone does not support in its options object

```
class MyView extends Backbone.View
  constructor: (foo, bar, options)->
    # locals foo and bar are now assigned
    @foo = foo
    @bar = bar
    super(options) # calls to Backbone.View with the normal options

myView = new MyView("foo","bar", {model: someModel, el: $('#someEl')})
myView.foo # "foo"
myView.model == someModel # true
```